# What does "-bash" mean in bash?

Tags: bash, special-characters

Is `-bash` login shell or something else .

I have a glance at this somewhere, not found from bash manual

If anyone has a nice doc or the answer...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a shell process where `argv[0]` begins with a `-` is treated as a login shell. This behavior started with the Bourne shell and was copied in `bash`. `argv[0]` is treated just like any other argument to a program. For instance `vi` and `ex` are frequently the same program, but the executable will behave differently depending on how it was invoked.

Whether a shell is a login shell or not influences which config files it reads, but what exactly that does differs from shell to shell.

From the GNU Bash man page.

> INVOCATION
>
> A login shell is one whose first character of argument zero is a -, or one started with the --login option.

Here's some information about login shells: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell